# Как сделать сколько пользователь раз нажал столько и срабатывала функция а не 1 раз

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть код, мне нужно что бы все это дело работало неограниченное количество раз. Я в принципе могу влаживать функцию в функцию к примеру раз 10,ну это понятное дело что бред. Нужно что бы работало столько раз сколько я пожелаю нажать. Поможет кто с такой детской задачей?

```
   let div = document.querySelector('.div-1');
    div.ondblclick = function f1(){
      div.classList.add('active');
      
      div.ondblclick = function f1(){
        div.classList.remove('active');  
      } 
    }
```

Comment: А вам не проще будет использовать [`div.classList.toggle('active')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)?

Comment: мне нужно что бы класс добавлялся и при повторном клике удалялся, неограниченное количество раз

Comment: Так эта функция и должна «переключать» класс: если он есть, удалять, если нет — добавлять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте варианты:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.div-1');

div.ondblclick = function f1(){
  div.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```
let div = document.querySelector('.div-1');

div.ondblclick = function f1(){
  if (div.classList.contains('active')) div.classList.remove('active');
  else div.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: все два варианта рабочие. только второй мне не понятен на данном уровне. воспользуюсь первым.спасибо

Comment: Когда вы щелкаете на элементе, функция проверяет, есть ли уже нужный класс в списке классов: `if (div.classList.contains('active'))`. Если есть, удаляет, если нет, добавляет. Поэтому сколько бы вы ни щелкали, она поочерёдно делает то одно, то другое. В первом варианте происходит то же самое, только «под капотом».